# Splitting "admin.py" of a Django project?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to split `admin.py` of a Django project into separate files but failed.

There's no information I can find from google about how to split it, so I have to try myself. Here's what I tried:

1. make a directory named `separated_admins` and put an empty `__init__.py` in it
2. create files in `separated_admins` directory, something like this:

   ```
   # file my_app/seperated_admins/Some_Model_admin.py

   from my_app.models import Some_Model
   from django.contrib import admin

   admin.site.register(Some_Model)
   ```
3. in `admin.py`, I added lines like:

   ```
   from my_app.seperated_admins import *
   ```

But I didn't see `Some_Model` in my admin site. Is my solution right? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `admin.py` is just a python module. So the right way of splitting it would be as follows:

- Create a folder called `admins` instead of `admin.py` file
- Use multiple files within the admin folder, like your `some_model_admin.py`
- Create a `__init__.py` in the `admins` folder and import * all the files into it.
- You might also want to include an [`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) to provide a clean interface.

Comment: Small note about >"and import * all the files into it" means many strings like `from Some_Model_admin import *` `from Some_Other_Model_admin import *` in `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

you should be importing from Some_Model_admin instead.

```
from my_app.seperated_admins.Some_Model_admin import *
```

things should be working fine then

alternatively you can import all the split files into the init in which case

```
from my_app.seperated_admins import *
```

should work