# Django: Moving .py files into a folder to tidy up

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project and I thought it would be good to tidy things up and put all my `.py` files into a folder.

My directory structure initially was the fairly straightforward:

```
[site]
├── [mysite]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

And now I have moved all of those `.py` files except `__init__.py` into the folder `py`.

```
[site]
├── [mysite]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── [py]
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       ├── views.py
│       └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

To ensure that this will work I went through and changed all the references to files to their new location. For example in `manage.py` I changed:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.py.settings")
```

I did this for all the references I could find. But the problem I am facing now is `admin.py` does not seem to be referenced or imported anywhere and when I make changes to it now it does not cause my test server to restart, so it is obviously disconnected from the project.

Is there some way to point Django to the new location of `admin.py`? Is there some parameter that can be put into `settings.py` that I'm missing?

EDIT: I've posted my own answer below, but if you have a better one please add it.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with one with of doing it, although it's not my ideal solution.

I found some inspiration in the accepted answer on this question:
[Splitting "admin.py" of a Django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118450/splitting-admin-py-of-a-django-project)

There it says that the `admin.py` file can be replaced with an `admin` folder and then inside it you can put an `__init__.py` file where you have your import statements for all your admin files.

So I did that but just put my import statement like this:

```
from mysite.py import admin
```

so that I can keep the `admin.py` file in the `py` folder with all the other files like I mentioned in the question.

However, as I mentioned, this is not ideal for me as it still means having the extra `admin` folder and I would rather find some other simpler way to do it, but I haven't found one. If you have a better answer please post it.